# Calculate count records from mysql group by fields

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My table in MySQL
http://joxi.ru/5mdWRV8tyQzyr1

My programm pass array users

```
$ids = [1, 3, 7];
```

My query for table:

```
SELECT responsible_id, count(id) as count
from test
WHERE active = 1
  AND status = 3
  AND responsible_id in (1, 3, 7)
GROUP BY responsible_id
ORDER BY count(id)
```

I get result http://joxi.ru/vAWYGq0IMxdjmW

But, I need also first row with responsible_id = 7 and count = 0 if not exist on table.

Comment: Minor tip: do `ORDER BY count`, i.e. order by column alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, use a `left join`:

```
SELECT v.responsible_id, count(t.id) as count
FROM (SELECT 1 as responsible_id UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as responsible_id UNION ALL
      SELECT 7 as responsible_id
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     test t
     ON t.responsible_id = v.responsible_id AND
        t.active = 1 AND
        t.status = 3
GROUP BY v.responsible_id
ORDER BY count(id);
```

Note that the conditions in the `WHERE` have been moved to the `ON` clause.